# Nonlinear heat equation

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Consider the following Cauchy problem

\begin{align}
\begin{cases}
\partial_t u=\sigma(t)\partial_{xx} u+ b(u),\; (t,x)\in[0,T]\times \mathbb R\\
u(0,x)=u_0(x)=Ce^{-x^2/2},
\end{cases}
\end{align}

where $\sigma(\cdot)$ is continuous (bounded if needed) and $b(\cdot)$ is bounded and Lipschitz continuous.

I am interested in representation for solutions of the latter equation, I know that if $b=0$ then the differential operator generates a semigroup which is connected to the diffusion $dX_t=\sqrt{2\sigma(t)}dB_t$ where $(B_t)$ is a Brownian Motion and then we can represent the solution y means of the Feynman-Kac formula.

I am now aware if we can still find a Feynman-Kac formula in this case where we have a nonlinear term $b(u)$, is there a representation for the solution?

If not, is it still possible to write this down as

$$u(t,x)=P_t( u_0)(x)+\int_0^t P_{t-s}(b(u))(x)ds$$

where $P_t$ is the Markov semigroup associated with the differential operator?

Last, if you know some reference that treats the heat equation with nonlinear terms please let me know!

Thanks in advance